# Pencil and holomorphic map $M\setminus B\to\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

On Griffiths and Harris, Principles of Algebraic Geometry, p.138, right after the proof of the Bertini's theorem. It says:

The essential point here is that a pencil $\{D_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\mathbb{P}^1}$ with base locus $B$ gives a holomorphic mapping $M\setminus B\to\mathbb{P}^1$ since by linearity every $p\in M]\setminus B$ is on a unique $D_\lambda$.

My questions are:

1. How to see the divisors in $\{D_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\mathbb{P}^1}$ cover the whole $M$? In other words, to any $p\in M\setminus B$, why is there always a divisor from the pencil s.t. $p$ is on it? (I can see the uniqueness though)
2. Why is the map $M\setminus B\to\mathbb{P}^1$ sending each point to the unique divisor containing it a holomorphic map? I don't see how is that related to Bertini's theorem as well as its proof.

Comment: For 1, let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be two different hyperplanes in $\mathbb P^n$, the pencil $aH_1+bH_2$ covers the projective space. For 2, the map is the restriction to complex submanifold $M$ of the linear projection $\mathbb P^n\setminus B\to \mathbb P^1$.

Comment: @AGlearner sorry what’s P^n? What’s the linear projection you described?

Comment: I thought the situation was the pencil come from a pencil of hyperplane sections of projective embedding $M\subset \mathbb P^n$. If that is not the case, let's work in general: Let $s_0,s_1$ be two linearly independent sections on a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ spanning the pencil. Let $x\in M$ be a point, then there is a unique $[a,b]\in \mathbb P^1$ s.t., $(as_0+bs_1)(x)=0$. For 2, assume $a\neq 0$ at point $x$, so $b$ is a function satisfying $s_0(x)+bs_1(x)=0$, i.e., $b=-s_1(x)/s_0(x)$ locally (well-defined since $s_0\neq 0$ around $x$), which is holomorphic.

Comment: @AGlearner this looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it below?